# Why use Redis instead of storage in normal variables?

Tags: node.js, redis

What is the advantage of using Redis for session storage over simply storing all data in variables inside your app?

Comment: So that sessions can survive crash of your app. And be accessible from multiple app instances.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - Thanks! Could you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the top of my head:

Pros of storing sessions in external storage (redis) vs in-process

- sessions survive crash of app server
- sessions are shared between all app servers (if you have more than one).

Cons:

- slower than storing in-process (because of network latency)
- requires setting up and managing the storage